# How to detect hold after pan/drag event (UIGestureRegonizer / iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios

Just wondered if you had any tips on recognising **first a drag (pan) gesture and then if the user keeps holding their finger, another "hold" event?**

So the effect I'm after is that the regular pan event does its thing then when the movement if finished, if the user holds their finger, after a short delay, another event occurs. **This event should continue to fire until the finger is lifted.** Hope that makes sense.

I tried combining `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but the long press event is more about tapping, holding then swiping. I want things the other way round. I also tried a regular tap event, but that doesn't fire until the finder is removed from the screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use a timer or dispatch_after to emulate your advanced recognizer.

```
-(void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture;
{

    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        fireEvent = YES;
        //Alternatively, use display_after
        [self performSelector:@selector(fireAnotherEventIfNecessary) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
    } else {
        fireEvent = NO;
    }
}

-(void)fireAnotherEventIfNecessary {

    if (fireEvent) {
        // Fire Event
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. So it stays in the original pan gesture, just fires off another if the fingers still down. I'll try it but thought that the (continuous) pan event wouldn't actually fire if the there is no touch movement? to complicate it further, the new even should be continuous too (ie, keep firing until the finger is lifted). Cheers